# Is Pearl the first Nintendo character to swear?

Tags: gaming-history, splatoon-2-octo-expansion

Splatoon 2's Octo Expansion has a song called "#$@%* Dudes Be #$@%* Sleepin", which was Pearl's demo before she joined Off The Hook. In it, Pearl earns a lengthy bleep to cover up some kind of expletives.

Have there been any other first party Nintendo characters that canonically said an expletive, in text or vocally?

Comment: How bad does a word have to be to count as an "expletive"? Does a weaker one like "damn", "hell", or "crap" count? What about if a word's offensive in one language but not another?

Comment: @Toomai I'm purposely keeping it ambiguous. And since I don't technically know what Pearl even said, I'm encouraging answerers to use their best judgement.

Answer (score 6):

(this answer is community wiki in case others want to add further notable examples)

EarthBound has some crappy dialogue. For Nintendo in the early 90's, this might have been a surprise. ([s](https://legendsoflocalization.com/surprising-swear-words-in-game-translations/))

[image: EarthBound NPC: "She quit talking about all that serious crap..."]

We don't technically know what character's narrating the DK Rap, but we do know they got washed the heck out with soap for [the Melee remix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU4vh4LX2Gk). ([s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcP91tQ4ZSM))

[image: DK Rap: "One hell of a guy"]

The fact that this line in Metroid Prime 3 was changed to "No!" in the Trilogy re-release is the real damming issue. ([s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flQZJZsl_FQ))

[image: Admiral Dane: "Damn! They're targeting the planetary-defense system."]

Xenoblade Chronicles was done by Nintendo of Europe, and it has a fair amount of people being dammed and hells being raised. ([s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FQW2ojet4k))

[image: Dickson: "Looks like the Mechon are hell-bent on taking us out."]

Answer (score 3):

I came by this picture from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6xu7aq/beepo_has_a_foul_mouth/). It is a screenshot from the game "Mario + Rabbids Kingdom Battle". There is also swearing there (although expletive).

[image: Screenshot]

In the comments from above Reddit's post, I see there is also referred to Peach 'swearing' in the game "Mario & Luigi Superstar Saga". In that game, the bad words are coming out of her mouths as bombs:

> DonSoLow: 
> Well if you consider Peach's "explosive language" from Mario & Luigi Superstar Saga, it's kinda the same.
>
> ehluigi: 
> That wasn't swearing though, that was her words coming out as bombs instead of words.

Comment: Does this count as a "first party Nintendo" character since the game (and as far as I know the character) was developed by Ubisoft not Nintendo?

Comment: I'm not sure if it the first one, but Pearl's song was not the first one (which was the question).

Comment: More clarifying what "first party" is. Conker's Bad Fur Day comes to mind as an early Nintendo game but was developed by Rare. While Mario is definitely a Nintendo character, the rest of the characters (to me) are Ubisoft.

Comment: @Twobe7 Presumably they need to get Nintendos approval on how they portray Mario.  It's such a big character for them.

Comment: @JMac agreed. But it's not Mario saying the expletive here, it's Beep-o who is unique to this game. Does that make Beep-o a Nintendo character or Ubisoft character?